# np.where evaluates 'if-true' even when condition is not met?

Tags: python

```
ex1 = {'value': '1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5', 'number': '1197916152', 'key': '44'}
ex2 = {'number': '1197916152', 'key': '2'}
```

I've got a dictionaries like above. I need to check if a `dict` contains `value` key, and if not, return `1`. I tried with the following:

```
np.where('value' in ex1, ex1['value'], 1)
np.where('value' in ex2, ex2['value'], 1)
```

And while it works fine with `ex1`, it returns an error with `ex2`:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last) ' in ()
>   ----> 1 np.where('value' in ex2, ex2['value'], 1)
>
> KeyError: 'value'

It seems `ex2['value']` seems to be evaluated even when a condition is not fulfilled. Am I right? And how can I adjust that?

Comment: Yes, but I was expecting that `ex2['value']` is not evaluated as condition `'value' in ex2` is not met.

Comment: The problem is `np.where` evaluates both arguments and then decides what to pick based on the condition.

Comment: Calling `np.where`, or any other function, always evaluates all the passed arguments, and trying to evaluate `ex2['value']` fails. Use instead the native Python construct, which is `<value-if-true> if <condition> else <value-if-false>` (e.g. `ex1['value'] if 'value' in ex1 else 1`), or, in the case of dicts, you can just do `ex1.get('value', 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simpler solution, use the dictionary `.get` method to fetch the content of the `value` key, and set `1` as default in case it does not exist:

```
ex1.get('value', 1)
```

---

```
ex1.get('value', 1)
# '1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5'

ex2.get('value', 1)
# 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.where('value' in ex2, ex2.get('value'), 1)
```